# How to generate a unique number from the current date and time in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Can someone help me with this please, I would like to generate an unique number based on the current time and date down to milliseconds. No two student have this number has it will be used as an id number. Also the beginning of the id number would start like this SN and the number follows 04072017123901.

Comment: Take a look at [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Check http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/, you can produce output string suitable for your needs and than convert it to number (i.e. int.Parse(your_formated_date).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` to get one long number that represent the current date/time but can’t be sure that this can be unique.

To get a unique id use the Guid();

```
Guid UniqueID = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: How would like add for eg. SN to the print out on report. SN would always be there

Comment: <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.studentNumber)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.studentNumber)
        </dd>

Comment: Hey Aristos is it possible to show me how the function would look please

Comment: @Jane What function ? From the info that I give you, you can make your program.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a unique number. Simply decide the time range and get the number of seconds between two datetimes. Use the module's function to ensure the results fit with the length of your unique Id.

```
string startTime = "1/06/2010";
var seconds = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(startTime)).TotalSeconds;

return Convert.ToInt32(seconds % 100000000);
```

Here I preferred 8 digits unique number.